# When does a MP level-alpha test not exist?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I’m currently reading about the Neyman-Pearson Lemma for the MP level-$\alpha$ test. My question is, when does there not exist a MP level-$\alpha$ test?

For example, suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\sigma$ is known, $\mu_0<\mu_1$, and $\mu_0=\mu$ is the null hypothesis. The particular question I’m working on asks if there’s any $\alpha$ for which a MP test exists, but after setting up the ratio of likelihood functions with alternative over null, I’m not sure why such a test wouldn’t exist. What must I check for and why?

Comment: What exactly are you testing? What is the alternative?

Comment: The null hypothesis is provided. The alternative hypothesis is that $\mu=\mu_1$.

Comment: What did you get as the likelihood ratio? These should have been added in the post itself IMHO.

Comment: Should’ve been in the post but I’m typing on an iPad (Computer was stolen), and so I tried providing the “minimally sufficient” info for the question. Will edit soon.